How to get the image preview with the google suggests api
I want to build a search functionality that is based on google suggests api. I aleready know that you can use "https://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=TERM" to get search suggestions but it is not very complete and I would like to know if any one know how to get better suggestions with images embed and detailed description like in firefox or chrome browser. Is there a different api endpoint that provides this additional data?

I searched on the internet and I found nothing relevent on this subject
